# Strange splash screen at shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, plymouth, software-uninstall, logo

I noticed that my Ubuntu 16.04 machine now has a very strange splash screen when shutting down:

[image]

I do not recognize this logo and a google reverse image search has yielded no results.

Does anyone know the software responsible for this?
I would like to uninstall it.

I've already tried going back to my default splash screen, without success

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Comment: The splash screen is just an image.  That looks like the Ubuntu-GNOME `plymouth` screen to me, but you can install that manually, via the package (where removing it won't remove the image anyway) or by adding now EOL GNOME packages (all flavors on 16.04 are now EOL except for Kylin; which applies to all GNOME software not used by the Unity desktop).

Comment: Thank you ! indeed this was due to a non-default `plymouth`. I'll investigate how this got installed ...